# Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen claim on this policy is processed in three hours or more.

Tags: probability

An insurance policy is written to cover a loss $X$ where $X$ has density function:

$f(x) = \frac38\cdot x^2$, in the interval $0\leq x\leq2$, and $f(x) = 0$, otherwise.

The time (in hours) to process a claim of size $x$, where $0\leq x\leq2$, is uniformly distributed on the interval $[x,2x]$.

***Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen claim on this policy is processed in three hours or more.***

In my perspective, it is necessary to use the Law of Total Probability.

I am not clear about how to find what is in the formula that is below as P(A / X=x). I also found the formula of conditional density function, but I do not know how to apply it to this problem. My guess is that as density is not equal to probability, I need to integrate that conditional density function to get the probability, but I am not sure. I would appreciate explanations about how to find that conditional density probability, the associate conditional probability, how to apply the Law of Total Probability to this problem, and in general, any way to solve this problem. My goal is to have clear those concepts.

[image: Conditional Density Function]

[image: Law of Total Probability]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an arbitrary $x$, the probability density function for claim processing time is 
$$f(z)=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & z< x \\
      \frac1x & x\leq z\leq 2x \\
      0 & 2x< z 
   \end{cases}
$$

Note that when $x=1.5$, the area under $f(z)$ where $z\geq3$ is $0$, while for $x=2$, the area under $f(z)$ is $1$. Since the function is linear, we can define the area under the curve as  $$\textrm{Area under the curve}=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & z< 1.5 \\
      2z-3 & 1.5\leq z\leq 2 \\
      0 & 2< z 
   \end{cases}
$$

So, the probability of an arbitrary $z$ having claim time over 3 hours is $$\frac{f(z)}{\textrm{length of }[z,2z]}=\frac{2z-3}z=2-\frac3z$$Obviously only when $1.5\leq z\leq2$, as otherwise, $f(z)=0$.

So, we integrate this function times the main probability distribution. This gives us $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac38x^2\cdot (2-\frac3x)\textrm{dx}=\int_{1.5}^2 \frac38x^2\cdot (2-\frac3x)\textrm{dx}=\frac38\cdot\bigg(\frac{2x^3}3-\frac{3x^2}2\bigg)\bigg\vert_{1.5}^2=\color{red}{\frac{11}{64}}$$

## Edit

In some sense, this problem involves two random variables, and an aggregation of their results. However, I think the following approach, while being less general than others, may serve as a good approach for many problems of this kind.

Suppose we have to find $P(B)$. We note that $$P(B)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(A)P(B|A) dA$$In intuitive terms, the meaning of this integral, is that we find the probability of each event in $A$, multiply it by the probability of $B$ given the event in $A$ happened, and then sum over all such events.

The tricky part of the computation is finding a general expression for $P(A)$ and $P(B|A)$. In this problem, $$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{2x-3}x$$ and $P(A)=\frac38x^2$.

Comment: Can you explain me how you get 2x-3? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wanted a linear equation such that $f(1.5)=0$ and $f(2)=1$. With two points, you can find a line. If this help, make sure to hit that green check mark underneath the voting buttons!

Comment: @Beginner See edits. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Beginner No problem! I'd like the accepted answer though if possible!

Comment: As you edited your answer, I erased mine. Can you explain more in depth how to find the conditional probability? What concepts, formulas, or theorems are you using to say that is equal to (2x-3)/x ? You wrote that is because is the length of interval. Why? I am trying to figure out what would I have to do if it were not uniform? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Beginner Sure! See edits

Comment: Thank you for the edition of your answer and your ideas. It seems that the integral that you wrote is wrong. Instead of P(B) you should write density function of B, correct? Probability and densities are not the same, right? Also you are not giving a clear explanation about how to calculate the conditional probability. You mentioned that is equal to (2x-3)/x but you not explain why and that is one of the fundamental parts of my question.

Comment: About this problem, what I still do not know how to calculate the joint density function, and the marginal density X at x. Please check the formula that I added in the question about the conditional density.

Answer (score 2):

Let we define the conditional processing rime r.v. as following $$T|X=x\sim U(x,2x)$$then the desired probability is $$P{=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)\Pr(T>3|X=x)dx\\=\int_{0}^{2}\dfrac{3}{8}x^2\Pr(T>3|X=x)dx\\=\int_{0}^{1.5}\dfrac{3}{8}x^2\Pr(T>3|X=x)dx+\int_{1.5}^{2}\dfrac{3}{8}x^2\Pr(T>3|X=x)dx\\=\int_{1.5}^{2}\dfrac{3}{8}x^2\Pr(T>3|X=x)dx\\=\\=\int_{1.5}^{2}\dfrac{3}{8}x^2\cdot\dfrac{2x-3}{x}dx\\=\int_{1.5}^{2}\dfrac{3}{4}x^2dx-\int_{1.5}^{2}\dfrac{9}{8}xdx\\={11\over 64}}$$P.S. notice that $\Pr(T>3|X=x)$ is the probability that $T$ is greater that $3$ while it belongs uniformly between $x<3<2x$. In fact $\Pr(T>3|X=x)$ is the area of a rectangle with length $2x-3$ and width $1\over x$ hence the uniform distribution. Literally using integral we have$$\Pr(T>3|X=x)=\Pr(2x>T>3|X=x)=\int_{3}^{2x}{1\over x}dt={2x-3\over x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is very nice! However, you did not explain how you got what you call Pr(T>3/X=x). The total probability law formula called in the same way. I think that it would be more accurate the density probability function of (T>3/X=x). What do you think about that idea?

Comment: If I get you correctly, that's not much more different but finding the distribution of $T>t|X=x$ is harder itself and makes the solution more complicated, but the idea itself is right. What I did in my solution was departing the total probability into grains of conditional probabilities and easily calculating each of them then after integrating all of them. Hope this appendix help you and I appreciate any question if you still had some ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! How you got (2x-3)/x? I do not understand how you did it. In fact, it is not in your solution. Can you add that part? I am sure that I am not the only one who has that doubt.

Comment: Ok! I added some more details. Is it helpful?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. However, it does not have sense to me that you can find an area multiplying two functions. Can you do that? You are not explaning how you got 2x-3, as well.  I do not understand how you can justifiy that without the double integral. I appreciate a lot the effort that you used to give me your ideas.

Comment: What about this one edit?

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. However, the integral of 1/x is ln x. Additionally, you are not explaining why what you call Pr (T>3/X=x) is equal to that Integral.. I appreciate a lot the time that you are using.

Comment: You're welcome! The integral is $\int{1\over x}dt$ which is $t\over x$ because when calculating $\Pr(T>t|X=x)$ you consider $x$ as constant not the differential variable.......

Comment: Thank your fast answer, ideas and your time. You wrote before that you were integrating with respect of x. Now that you changed to integrated with respect of t, it has sense. I gave you the bounty! My only doubt at this point about your answer, and it is a very important one, is that you are trying to satisfy two conditions. It seems to me that you are trying to get Pr(T>3 and X=x). It seems that in this case they are equal. Which formula/theorem are you using to say that your result for P(T>3/X=x) is conditional probability? This is very important to have a method for different problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the mistake that I was doing is very interesting.

When we analyze the formula for the Law of Total Probability, we have P(A/X=x).

Please check this image:

[image: Law of Total Probability]

In some way, the formula is wrong. Instead of Pr(A/X=x) should be f(A/X=x), ***the density probability function***. Something significant is that probability and density function are not the same. Density functions are only for continuous random variables. We integrate density functions to get a probability.

Thus, we only need to find f(A/X=x), that in our problem is 1/x because the time is uniformly distributed between x and 2x. We multiply (1/x) by the density function that is given (3/8)x^2, and we get (3/8)x that is the joint density function. In our problem, it would be f(x,t).

[image]

After we have the joint density function, we only need to do the double integral for the limits related to the problem.

There are two ways to do it. Either we integrate first with respect of t, and later with respect of x, or viceversa. We will get the same result.

In the following solution, the author integrated with respect of x first, and later with respect of t.

I found a solution to this problem that in the website of the University of Illinois, written by Dr. Krzysztof Ostaszewski, who is an expert in probability, and author of several books. Here is the solution:

[image: First Part]

[image: Second Part]